# What is the best way to chain promises in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I know this might seem dumb on my end, but I'm not sure the best way to go about this.

I have a for loop right now that loops through inventory items and then a socket is triggered to get a foreign key back from MySql for that specific item.  That works completely fine, but after that key is retrieved I need to subtract a quantity for that item.  I figured that I could just chain another socket right after that one, but it looks like after that first socket is triggered, by the time the second one triggers, the loop has already finished, which is giving me the incorrect quantities for these items.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish client side

```js
    BinTestMethod(){

        var ItemObject = [
            {Serial: "AMSD0027LF", Quantity: 2},
            {Serial: "AMSD0003LF", Quantity: 1},
        ]

       // console.log(ItemObject[0]);
        //console.log(ItemObject.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < ItemObject.length; i++){
            //console.log(ItemObject.length);
            console.log(ItemObject[i].Serial);
            var id;
            var quantity = ItemObject[i].Quantity;

            socket.emit('selectParentFromInventory', ItemObject[i], function (result){
                id = result[0].ParentID;
                //console.log(id);
                //console.log(quantity);
                this.UpdateQuantity(quantity, id);
            }.bind(this));


        }
    }

   UpdateQuantity(Quantity, ID){
        console.log(Quantity);
        socket.emit('updateParentQuantity', Quantity, ID, (boolean) => {})
    }
```

Here are the promises

```js
export const selectParentFromInventory = async (ItemObject) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const getParentID = `SELECT ParentID FROM console.inventory WHERE Serial = '${ItemObject.Serial}'`;
            const response = await db(getParentID, "ParentID");
            //console.log(response);
            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR inventory.selectParentFromInventory: " + e);
            reject(e);
        } 
    });   
};

export const updateParentQuantity = (Quantity, ID) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let updateQuantity;
        console.log(ID);

        try {
                updateQuantity = `UPDATE console.inventory_items SET QuantityOnHand = QuantityOnHand - ${Quantity} WHERE ID = "${ID}"`

            //console.log(response);
            const response = await db(updateQuantity, `Updating Quantity`);
            resolve(response);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR inventory.updateQuantity: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Here are the sockets

```js
    socket.on('selectParentFromInventory', (data, callback) => {
        const results = selectParentFromInventory(data).then((results) => {
            callback(results);
        })
    });

    socket.on('updateParentQuantity', async (ItemObject, ID, callback) => {
        try {
            const results = await updateParentQuantity(ItemObject, ID);
            if (results.affectedRows === 1) {
                callback(true);
                //socket.emit("refreshJobPage", false, "");
            }
            callback(false);
        }
        catch (error) {}
    });
```

When I run this the ID's that I receive back from the call are correct, but when I console log the quantities, it gives me the number 1 each time. Instead I should be getting the quantities 1 and 2.

A suggestion that I thought of trying was to just pass in the entire ItemObject to the Socket and then loop within the socket itself, but not sure if that would be a good idea or not.

I know my code is probably not logically correct, but if anyone has some good suggestions on how I could make this work, it would be much appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand everything you're asking, but I can help you with one aspect of your `for` loop.

In a nutshell, change your definition of the `quantity` variable to `const`.  This will give it a unique and separate value for each iteration through the `for` loop and since you're not modifying it after declaration, it is a natural for `const`, though `let` would also work just fine.

And, then move the declaration of the `id` variable inside the callback since it is only needed there and use `const`.  This is probably not actually required, but is a good coding practice so you don't have multiple callbacks sharing the same variable.

This works because `const` and `let` are block-scoped. They create a new instance of the variable every time you enter the block. `var` is function scoped. Each iteration of the for loop is considered a new block so it creates a new copy of any variable defined within the loop using `const` or `let`. So, even though the promise takes awhile to finish and the `for` loop keeps going, each iteration of the loop has its own `const` and `let` variables so the right ones are used when the promise finally finishes. 99.999% of the time, you should be using `let` or `const` now, not `var`.

So change this:

```
  BinTestMethod(){

        var ItemObject = [
            {Serial: "AMSD0027LF", Quantity: 2},
            {Serial: "AMSD0003LF", Quantity: 1},
        ]

       // console.log(ItemObject[0]);
        //console.log(ItemObject.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < ItemObject.length; i++){
            //console.log(ItemObject.length);
            console.log(ItemObject[i].Serial);
            var id;
            var quantity = ItemObject[i].Quantity;

            socket.emit('selectParentFromInventory', ItemObject[i], function (result){
                id = result[0].ParentID;
                //console.log(id);
                //console.log(quantity);
                this.UpdateQuantity(quantity, id);
            }.bind(this));


        }
    }

   UpdateQuantity(Quantity, ID){
        console.log(Quantity);
        socket.emit('updateParentQuantity', Quantity, ID, (boolean) => {})
    }
```

to this:

```
  BinTestMethod(){

        var ItemObject = [
            {Serial: "AMSD0027LF", Quantity: 2},
            {Serial: "AMSD0003LF", Quantity: 1},
        ]

       // console.log(ItemObject[0]);
        //console.log(ItemObject.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < ItemObject.length; i++){
            const quantity = ItemObject[i].Quantity;

            socket.emit('selectParentFromInventory', ItemObject[i], function (result){
                const id = result[0].ParentID;
                //console.log(id);
                //console.log(quantity);
                this.UpdateQuantity(quantity, id);
            }.bind(this));
        }
    }

   UpdateQuantity(Quantity, ID){
        console.log(Quantity);
        socket.emit('updateParentQuantity', Quantity, ID, (boolean) => {})
    }
```

Comment: My thinking is that the for loop with still iterate faster than the promises can finish, so I will probably get the same output I did before, but I will give it a try.

Comment: @Michael - Get my latest edit as I realized that the `quantity` variable also has to be fixed.  Yes, the loop goes faster, but using `const` or `let` keeps a separate value of the variable for EACH iteration of the loop so it will maintain the desired value, even over time and as the `for` loop continues to run.

Comment: @Michael - Because `const` and `let` are block-scoped.  They create a new instance of the variable every time you enter the block.  `var` is function scoped.  Each iteration of the `for` loop is considered a new block so it creates a new copy of any variable defined within the loop using `const` or `let`.  So, even though the promise takes awhile to finish and the `for` loop keeps going, each iteration of the loop has its own `const` and `let` variables so the right ones are used when the promise finally finishes.  99.999% of the time, you should be using `let` or `const` now, not `var`.

Comment: Ok this makes more sense.  I appreciate your help!